# Is there a better way to create a filter based on parameter input

Tags: powershell, api, parameters, filtering

I want my function to be able to accumulatively filter data based on parameter input. Here is my attempt:

```
 function Get-People {


    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(mandatory=$false,position=0)]
        [string]$Name,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$Country,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$State,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$City,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$IDNumber
    )

    $uri = "https://some.site.com/api/endpoint"
    $header = $script:HeaderData
    $response = invoke-restmethod -uri $uri -header $header -method get -contenttype "application/json"

    if ($IDNumber) {$response = $response | ?{$_.idnumber -eq $IDNumber}}
    if ($Name) {$response = $response | ?{$_.name -like $Name}}
    if ($City) {$response = $response | ?{$_.city -like $City}}
    if ($State) {$response = $response | ?{$_.state -like $State}}
    if ($Country) {$response = $response | ?{$_.country -like $Country}}

    $response

}
```

This works pretty well. I can run the command below

```
get-people -Country US -State Texas -City Austin -Name Jo*
```

and it will return everyone in Austin, TX, US with names starting with "Jo".

It just feels like a really clunky solution, and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: would you please use `ConvertTo-CSV` on your `$Response` data to make a pseudo file and then post the 1st three or four lines from that? as it stands, you have not shown any input data ... and that makes giving you any meaningful help distinctly difficult. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the following approach.

- Build a filter according to the passed parameter
- Filter the response once with that final filter

To achieve this, you can store the filter script blocks into a list variable, then create a new condition by combining all conditions into one.

The resulting function would look like this

(Note that `$FakeResponse` was added for the sole purpose of demonstrating the end result with a fake data set since I can't make an API call to your unkwnown API)

```
function Get-People {


    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        $FakeResponse,
        [parameter(mandatory = $false, position = 0)]
        [string]$Name,
        [parameter(mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$Country,
        [parameter(mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$State,
        [parameter(mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$City,
        [parameter(mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$IDNumber
    )

    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('FakeResponse')) {
        $response = $FakeResponse
    }
    else {
        $uri = "https://some.site.com/api/endpoint"
        $header = $script:HeaderData
        $response = invoke-restmethod -uri $uri -header $header -method get -contenttype "application/json"
    }

    $Conditions = [System.Collections.Generic.List[scriptblock]]::new()

    Foreach ($k in $PSBoundParameters.Keys) {
        switch ($k) {
            'Name' { $Conditions.Add( { $_.name -like $Name }) }
            'Country' { $Conditions.Add( { $_.country -like $Country }) }
            'State' { $Conditions.Add( { $_.state -like $State }) }
            'City' { $Conditions.Add( { $_.city -like $City } ) }
            'IDNumber' { $Conditions.Add( { $_.idnumber -eq $IDNumber }) }
        }
    }

    if ($Conditions.Count -ge 1) {
        $FinalCondition = [scriptblock]::Create(($Conditions -join ' -and '))
        Write-Verbose "Filter applied: $($FinalCondition.ToString())"
        return $response.Where($FinalCondition)
    }
    else {
        return $Response
    }
}
```

For demonstration purpose, I added a `Write-Verbose` for the end filter. 
Also for demonstration purpose, here's a fake data set to test the function against.

```
$TestData = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name     = 'Morty'
        IDNumber = 'C-299'
        City     = 'Montreal'
        State    = 'Quebec'
        Country  = 'Canada'
    },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name     = 'Rick'
        IDNumber = 'C-137'
        City     = 'Seattle'
        State    = 'Washinton'
        Country  = 'USA'
    },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name     = 'Jerry'
        IDNumber = '?'
        City     = 'Seattle'
        State    = 'Washinton'
        Country  = 'USA'
    }
)
```

Finally, the actual call:

```
get-people -City 'Seattle' -Country USA -FakeResponse $TestData -Verbose | ft
```

And the result:

[image: Sample result]